# Update provisioning profile in xCode project fastlane sigh command

Tags: ios, fastlane

I'm using Fastlane for automatic deploy of a project for multiple clients. For each I set a new and different bundle_identifier. I use produce command to create the app in the dev portal.Then I'm using sigh command to generate and download provisioning profile for the new app created in the dev portal. I ran into a problem. It downloads and installs the profile. The problem is that if I look up into my project and I choose the target I want to deploy and look up into the signing(release) section the provisioning profile is not set. When using gym I'm getting an error.

I post here contents of my fastfile. Maybe I'm using something wrong or I'm missing something.

```
update_info_plist(
    plist_path: 'Plist.plist',
    xcodeproj: 'PathToMyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj',
    block: lambda { |plist|
    plist['CFBundleDisplayName'] = 'App 1'
    plist['CFBundleIdentifier'] = 'com.xxx.App1'
    plist['CFBundleName'] = 'App1'
    }
)

ENV["GYM_WORKSPACE"] = 'MyProject.xcworkspace'

produce(
username: 'xxx@xxx.xxx',
app_identifier: 'com.xxx.App1',
app_name: 'App1',
skip_itc: true,
)

sigh(
username: 'xxx@xxx.xxx',
app_identifier: 'com.xxx.App1',
provisioning_name: 'App1DistribProvProf',
output_path: 'PathToMyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj',
adhoc: true,
)

update_project_provisioning(
xcodeproj: 'PathToMyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj',
target_filter: '.*App1Target1.*'
)

#ENV["PROFILE_UUID"] = lane_context[SharedValues::SIGH_UDID]
gym(scheme: 'App1Scheme', export_method: 'ad-hoc')
```

Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful to post the commands you're running and/or your `Fastfile`

Comment: Hy, I've posted the commands I'm running.

Comment: The prov profile you are getting with sigh surelly will be the distribution one or dev. Not the ad-hoc needed by Gym. Which error it's throws?